# MYSQL join and order by

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a search, which includes keyword and location/radius options.
I have 1 table which holds location (latitude and longitude) information for the jobs (jobs can have multiple locations).
I have another table which has all the other information for the job, like title.

```
table jobs:
+----------+---------+
|  jobref  |  title  |
+----------+---------+

table jobs_locations:
+----------+------------+-------------+
|  jobref  |  latitude  |  longitude  |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

When a user inputs a location, I generate a latitude and longitude.
I can then get all the jobref's of from 'jobs_locations' within a radius of that location using a select like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT jobref, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$lat.") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$lon.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM jobs_locations 
HAVING distance < ".$distance;
```

I also search the main 'jobs' table for jobs which have a title matching the user input keywords:

```
"SELECT *, 
MATCH(`title`) 
AGAINST ('".$keywords."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS Relevance 
FROM jobs 
WHERE MATCH(`title`) 
AGAINST ('".$keywords."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

My question is, how can I join these 2 queries together, to get jobs which match the keywords and location/radius input, and then ORDER BY distance (or relevance, if the user wants) ??

**EDIT::**

so far ive tried this.. which didnt work - it took FOREVER and the mysql server just went away. What would be a better, faster way of doing this?

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH(jobs.title) 
AGAINST ('developer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS Relevance,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.27) ) * cos( radians( jobs_locations.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( jobs_locations.longitude ) - radians(-0.83) ) + sin( radians(51.27) ) * sin( radians( jobs_locations.latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM jobs 
INNER JOIN jobs_locations ON jobs.jobref = jobs_locations.jobref 
WHERE MATCH(jobs.title) 
AGAINST ('developer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND jobs.salary_per = 'annum' 
HAVING distance < 15 
ORDER BY Relevance DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: did you try using `UNION` or you can use subqueries select * from table where (query2).

Comment: i tried your exact query and it worked fine in my localhost. What error are you getting??

Comment: @MikeRoss, sorry updated my edit - seems it would work, just it takes forever. Looks like i need a better way of doing this?

Comment: @rpsep2 why are you doing acos and cos on a constant? Also can yoau give the data types of your table. It could be the reuason of your performance issues

Comment: depending on how many records you are searching through, the trig might get expensive, could you not limit the results to only latitudes/longitudes in range? (then do the expensive calculations on only the possible matches)

Comment: Take a look at the spatial features of mySQL, maybe you can use them. PostGreSQL has a much better support for spatial data, if you will consider using another database system